# Storing a bunch of foreign keys efficiently (Serialize vs New Table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to keep a list of `user_id`s that have viewed a piece of content to calculate unique user views. The `user_id` is an `INT(10)` field.

I could create a table with `user_id`, `content_id`, and `viewed` and add a row everytime a user views content, but this seems slow. For every piece of content the user views, I will have to query something like

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM viewed_table WHERE content_id = $content_id;`

to get the amount of views, and then

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM viewed_table WHERE user_id = $user_id AND content_id = $content_id;`

to see whether or not the user has viewed this content, and then insert a row if not. (2 or 3 additional queries every time a user looks at something).

**OR...**

Should I add a `viewed` field to my content table and `unserialize()` / `serialize()` the array each time I add a `user_id`? `json_encode()` is another similar option which seems faster on large data sets.

**Which option is the fastest/ most scalable for a growing site? Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of a thumb: serializing relational data in general, foreign keys in particular == highway to hell.

Have a table where you store sums of all views and you only increase/decrease it. That should be faster than `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM viewed_table WHERE content_id = $content_id;`

To see if a given user has already viewed given page `SELECT 1 FROM viewed_table WHERE user_id = $user_id AND content_id = $content_id LIMIT 1;`. This will either return 0 or 1 rows, so you only need to check for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
viewed_table
----------------------------
user_id int(10)
content_id int(10)
primary key (user_id, content_id)
```

To insert a record:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO viewed_table (user_id, content_id) VALUES ($user_id, $content_id)
```

Your affected_rows count will show whether this is a new row (the user hasn't viewed the content). No select required for that one.

If you wish to implement the totals table, this is also the point at which you'd add one to the total for the selected content_id.

```
viewed_table_totals
----------------------------
content_id int(10)
view_count int(10)
primary key (content_id)
```

Updating the row:

```
INSERT INTO viewed_table_totals (content_id, view_count) VALUES($content_id, 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE view_count = view_count + 1
```

Since you want unique visits, you cannot avoid storing each user visit.

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt the first option.

The cost of serializing/unserializing the list of ids every time you want to calculate the number of views, or whenever someone reads an article would be orders of magnitude slower than COUNTing on a well-indexed 2nd table.

You could further improve this by storing the count in memory (with something like Memcached or Redis), or by adding a view_count column to the content table and just incrementing that number whenever you add to the viewed_table.